# Can Facebook/Google cause site to not load?

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-social-plugins

This might sound like a silly question, but yesterday none of our sites would load. After contacting the hosting company they said that

> In this instance, it would appear that your site is hanging waiting for a response from an external component / website (looking at your code, I see references to Facebook, Google and online apps at a glance).

We've never had this problem before and the sites have been using the social plugins for months so I wondered if anybody else experienced this problem yesterday?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a random stab in the dark but I wonder if this was related in any way to the anonymous threats on Facebook. I have experienced similar problems before with a twitter plugin, it could take a few seconds for the plugin to ping back the tweets and the rest of the page was hanging while twitter was doing their thing.

To ensure this doesn't happen again you could call your social plugin's on page load if its a viable solution. At the end of the day do you want your page load time to depend on other services outside of your control or not?

edit: @Jason McClellan 's answer is spot on. I believe the combo of out answers sort out your question. I Never include script in the head if I don't control the resource! That can indefinitely hang your page.

edit2: Don't know why I'm getting down rated for this answer was just trying to relate it to an experience of mine. I'm not extremely experienced with Facebook plugins but when I was noticing an issue with my twitter plugin, I did exactly what @Jason McClellan has said with his answer to make sure that all your html gets rendered before the scripts are even requested, then ensured that the page could display correctly with or without the twitter content so the user experience was not dependant on an external resource. The twitter plugin I was using had an initiation function which I had to call to fire up the script. The simplest way to call this would be with:

```
    <body onload='init()'>
```

if you have another script you are loading with the page you could use something along the lines of

```
    window.onload = function() {
        init();
    }
```

from within your external script.

Sorry I can't give an answer specific to the Facebook plugin. Maybe someone with more experience in the Facebook plugins could elaborate in the comments :D

edit3: also this community based tool suggests that quiet a few people where seeing a bit of facebook downtime when you experienced it - [Facebook status at DownRightNow](http://downrightnow.com/facebook)

edit4: I dont have the "Privelages" to comment on Jason's q as im pretty new here ... but in answer to your comment there, the stuff in the head that you describe is what loads in the schema for facebook mark-up language (fbml) , so a mark-up language like html, but geared up for you to use the facebook api. So you can do stuff like:

```
    <fb:comments xid="titans_comments" canpost="true" candelete="false" returnurl="http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/titans/">
    <fb:title>Talk about the Titans</fb:title>
    </fb:comments>
```

To wack some comments straight into your page - [fbml developers guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/)

Your comment there also suggests you are not including a script for your page to load so it renders our previous answers not as important, you need to include the fbml stuff in the head before you use fbml in your page so don't move it :D

but @jason McClellan's answer is something that everyone should do on their project (unless there is a reason not to) as it allows for the user to see something before the browser fires off requests for the scripts. At the end of the day we're in this game to make pretty stuff for our users!

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, how do I call them on page load? The actual plugins are contained within the <body></body> tags

Comment: There's no reported issues with the Facebook API and the response time is normal: https://developers.facebook.com/live_status

Comment: Thanks I'll try that - sorry I didn't know you'd been down rated for your help. You shouldn't have been it's been helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the details, I can tell you that when you load Javascript via `<script></script>` tags the browser waits for the request to finish before moving on. So, if you load JS files in the `<head></head>` section, nothing will render on-screen until they load successfully. 404s here will kill you, as will slow connections.

If you have in-line JS, it's best to put it at the very bottom of your `<body></body>` section so that it does not interrupt browser rendering. Do this for JS files in your `<head></head>` section if your code architecture allows it.

Comment: Thanks that sounds exactly like what I need to do. The only code that I have in the <head></head> is the <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> code that facebook say should be there as well as the facebook meta property tags. Can I move those to the bottom? There's no javascript relating to either facebook or google in the header. Although it does seem to be loading them as the same time.

Comment: I found the information for the facebook stuff on this page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Comment: The xmlns information needs to remain in your `<html>` tag, which should not be inside of `<head></head>`. @Jon Lee-White did a good job expanding. I don't have any direct experience with FB integration, though, so I'm sorry I can't be of more specific help.